# Getter not defined for static variable and also for method declared in the class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class AuthService defined under lib/services/authService.dart
The class has 1 static field and one static method. 
But I am not able to access the static fields and method in my lib/screenpage.dart

I tried the same class in dartPad and it is working fine. But VS Code shows that the method and getter is not defined for the class

Tried moving around with creating instance variables and also setting getter but it is not working

Tried to restart VS code

```
class AuthService {

static final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

static Future<void> _signInWithEmailAndLink(_userEmail) async => await _auth.sendSignInWithEmailLink(
      email: _userEmail,
      url: '<Url with domain from your Firebase project>',
      );

}
```

And inside my LoginPage.dart

```
final  auth = await AuthService._auth;

--error ( The getter '_auth' isn't defined for the class 'AuthService'.
Try importing the library that defines '_auth', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named '_auth')

 validationAndLogin() async {
    await AuthService._signInWithEmailAndLink(_email);
    }
  }

The method '_signInWithEmailAndLink' isn't defined for the class 'AuthService'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named '_signInWithEmailAndLink'.dart(undefine
```

I don't know what exactly I am missing in this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility):

> [...] identifiers that start with an underscore (_) are visible only inside the library.

Which means that using underscore as a prefix of a class, variable or function name, makes it private. That's why you cannot access those properties from another file.